# CKEditor in production not showing in admin panel

Tags: django, ckeditor

I've launched my project into production, CKEditior and CKEditor_uploader both worked  on my local server but now doesn't show on my production admin panel. Any ideas why it may not be showing would be greatly appreciated. Or any alternative ways to implement richtext and image uploading to blog posts in django admin.

***UPDATE**
I have some how got the CKEditor back but I cannot get the uploader to work, I have followed all documentation to a tee.

```
settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home/martinhenso/public_html/static/images/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home/martinhenso/public_html/static')
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('martinhensonphotography.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
        class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    blog_article = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    blog_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import PostImage, EnterImage, BlogPost, Topic

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(PostImage)
admin.site.register(BlogPost)
admin.site.register(EnterImage)
admin.site.register(Topic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_files')
]
```

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Location of static files are must be mension in nginx config file

Or

After entering the comment there will be a folder created 'static_files' inside static folder copy all the static files to to main static folder

Comment: Hi, I have done this command multiple times and it never has anything to collect. I've also removed the code and re implemented wand re migrated